# Why automatically released this memory at android?

Tags: android, memory, android-appwidget

I have some memory problems about my android appwiget,
(It's small toy appwidget based drawable animation repeat)

So I watched my memory viewer in Android Studio.

I found my app's memory increased at initial time, but when it doesn't enough memory it automatically release some memory.

1. I want to know what android function make this.
2. Can I control this release function with java code?

*I tested at real device android ver 4.42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), which is the process of removing from the memory the objects that are no longer required. You can have a good idea of how it works in Java [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).

In Android (and Java in general) you can **suggest** the virtual machine to do it with the [System.gc()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#gc()) call. Note, though, that it:

> Indicates to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector. Note that this is a hint only. There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run.

Comment: Thnaks! I exactly got what gc's meaning :)